# Django ListView mixin from Django documentation throws an error, why

Tags: python, django, mixins, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to adopt the [Django documentation example on using class based views with mixins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) in order to be able to make a simple way of downloading the objects in a list view in CSV format, but I am failing miserably and do not really see what I am doing wrong.

I have a view defined as:

```
class MyObjectList(CSVResponseMixin,
                   MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin,
                   BaseListView
                   ):
    object_type = None
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        object_type = self.object_type
        ...some code...
        return context

    def render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs):
        if self.request.GET.get('format', '') == 'csv':
            return CSVReponseMixin.render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs)
        else:
            return MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin.render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs)
```

the mixin is:

```
class CSVResponseMixin(object):
    def render_to_response(self, ctx, **kwargs):
        return self.HttpResponse.render_to_response(self.convert_to_csv(ctx), **kwargs)

    def conver_to_csv(ctx):
        return do_csv_magic(ctx)
```

and in `urls.py` the view is called as:

```
url(r'^list/foos/$',
    MyObjectList.as_view(object_type="someobject", model=models.MyModel),
    name="myobjects",
)
```

However when I try to access the view *without* the `?format=csv` query, I get a `TypeError`

```
Exception Value:  __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in render_to_response, line 97
```

**EDIT**: I added some details to the question and ended up implementing this with a different approach, but I still want to know what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you're overdoing it. I'm not sure what is your intention here, but I've learned that the best approach is to find the closest generic view to what you're trying to do and simply extend it in `views.py`. Examples are many, but I invite you to check my  code at https://bitbucket.org/BerislavLopac/resume/src/d7cfcf9c370b/resume_app/myproject/web/views.py.

Comment: I probably anonymized the code too much, the intention is to be able to download a list view in arbitrary file formats.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response), `render_to_response` only takes the following arguments: `template_name, dictionary, context_instance, mimetype`

Therefore within `FooResponseMixin` when you're calling:

```
self.HttpResponse.render_to_response(self.mutilate_context(ctx), **kwargs)
```

You're passing in extra arguments within `kwargs` that `render_to_response` doesn't accept.  Either remove the `**kwargs` or assign only what you need from it to variables to pass in to the accepted arguments.